# Two column checkboxes layout using just css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code is a dynamically generated part of a form and I only can style it using css.

No html changes but for the names of the classes with the exception of:  classes "element" and "formField" as they are used as  common classes for other elements in the form.

The layout I am looking for is a two column label-checkbox. As you can see in the code, I have 4 label-checkbox items. I need item 0 and 1 in a column and in another column next to it, item 2 and 3.

I know the tables should be gone for good, I agree but please help me here, I am going to build the whole site again but I don't have the time just yet.

```
<div class="element" id="mycat">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="30%" align="right"><div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat0">Category 0</label></div></td>
<td width="70%" align="left">
<div id="div_eCat0" style="float:left">
<input type="checkbox" name="eCat0" value="1" class="formField"> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<div class="element" id="mycat">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="30%" align="right"><div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat1">Category 1</label></div></td>
<td width="70%" align="left">
<div id="div_eCat1" style="float:left">
<input type="checkbox" name="eCat1" value="1" class="formField"> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<div class="element" id="mycat">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="30%" align="right"><div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat2">Category 2</label></div></td>
<td width="70%" align="left">
<div id="div_eCat2" style="float:left">
<input type="checkbox" name="eCat2" value="1" class="formField"> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<div class="element" id="mycat">
<table width="100%" border="0" style="">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="30%" align="right"><div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat3">Category 3</label></div></td>
<td width="70%" align="left">
<div id="div_eCat3" style="float:left">
<input type="checkbox" name="eCat3" value="1" class="formField"> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: annnnnnnd your css?

Comment: Whaw you have a lot of table with inline styles. Going old school

Comment: Remove the JavaScript and jQuery tags if you want a CSS only solution. Also, you **cannot have more than one of the same id assigned to different elements**. So rename those 3 `id="myCat"` to `myCat1`, `myCat2`, .etc..

Comment: You should also [associate label elements to associate text labels with form controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html) (tl;dr see Examples) via `label[for]` and `id`s on form field elements (most inputs, select, textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `float` and `clear` in order to do that. Here is an example.

```css
.element{
  float:right;
}

.element:nth-child(odd){
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" id="mycat">
            <table width="100%" border="0" style="">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%" align="right">
                            <div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat0">Category 0</label></div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="70%" align="left">
                            <div id="div_eCat0" style="float:left">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="eCat0" value="1" class="formField"> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="element" id="mycat">
            <table width="100%" border="0" style="">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%" align="right">
                            <div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat1">Category 1</label></div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="70%" align="left">
                            <div id="div_eCat1" style="float:left">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="eCat1" value="1" class="formField"> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="element" id="mycat">
            <table width="100%" border="0" style="">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%" align="right">
                            <div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat2">Category 2</label></div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="70%" align="left">
                            <div id="div_eCat2" style="float:left">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="eCat2" value="1" class="formField"> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="element" id="mycat">
            <table width="100%" border="0" style="">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30%" align="right">
                            <div style="float:right"><label id="lbl_eCat3">Category 3</label></div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="70%" align="left">
                            <div id="div_eCat3" style="float:left">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="eCat3" value="1" class="formField"> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can style the parent element of those four divs, you can set

```
.parent {
    columns: 2;
}
```

This will work in IE10+. https://jsfiddle.net/c979dxLe/1/

You can also set the width of the columns. Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 0):

I did this for some md-checkboxes in my parent div, and they are column-first ordered! Like this:

```
1                                              4
2                                              5
3
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    columns: 2;
}
.parent > * {
    width: 100%;
}
```